# How to customize pagination for the taxonomy term view page for different vocabulary?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have 3 vocabularies as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

And I have default *Taxonomy term* view page with 10 items per page as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to display 12 items per page only for the *taxonomy term pages* which are related to the *terms* of *Categories* vocabulary. Should I create new *Taxonomy term* view page for *Categories* vocabulary or is it possible to configure pagination using *HOOK_preprocess_taxonomy_term* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module which helped me set custom pagination and view modes by creating *taxonomy view page* for different taxonomy terms and vocabularies. Some details about this module (from its project page):

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice. Using TVI you can easily create custom views to output all terms in X vocabulary.
>
> TVI will try not to interfere with views or taxonomy/term page displays if no TVI views exist for the current page request.